# Fibonacci Function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, recursion, fibonacci

I am attempting to create a function for the Fibonacci numbers using a `for` loop. My code is as follows:

```
function fib = fibGenerator(N) 
fib(1) = 0;
fib(2) = 1;
for i = 3:N
   fib(i) = fib(i-1)+fib(i-2);
end
```

The following error message is displayed: `Variable fib must be of data type uint32. It is currently of type double. Check where the variable is assigned a value.`

I'm unsure of how to correct this.

**Update**

```
function fib = fibGenerator(N) 
fibGenerator(1) = uint32(0);
fibGenerator(2) = uint32(1);
for i = 3:N
  fibGenerator(i) = fibGenerator(i-1)+fibGenerator(i-2);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast when you initially create `fib`: `fib(1) = uint32(0);`

Here is an example demonstrating this. When creating x you decide the type. Even if later assignments are double or of other types, it will keep its type.

```
>> x=uint32(1)
x =
  uint32
   1
>> x(2)=double(2)
x =
  1×2 uint32 row vector
   1   2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I would not have thought of this! I made the adjustment, but I am now getting the error message 'Output argument "fib" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "fibGenerator" '.

Comment: You changed the name of the variable from `fib` to `fibGenerator`. Revert that change and it will work.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the following error message is displayed 'Variable fib must be of size [1 1]. It is currently of size [1 5]. Check where the variable is assigned a value.'

Comment: That's what I thought, but the following error message is displayed 'Variable fib must be of size [1 1]. It is currently of size [1 5]. Check where the variable is assigned a value.'

Comment: Your code generates the first n fibonacci numbers. What is your task, to generate only the n-th one?

Comment: I believe so. I need to generate the nth term in the sequence and assign this value to the variable 'fib'

Comment: That is telling you what's wrong. I guess there must be also an assignment telling you what to do? A `fib=fib(end)` at the end of your function should fix it, returning only the last one.

Comment: Yes, it has. Thank you a lot for your patience!